# MySQL database connection

Tags: node.js, express

Is writing a MySQL connection in express middle Good or Bad.

I am trying to connect MySQL database for my REST API in express middleware,
so i am confused that it generate lot of connection to MySQL server as Middleware get executed every time an API is called.
Please suggest if there is any better way.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    global.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        'host'     : 'localhost',
        'user'     : 'db_user',
        'password' : '12345',
        'database' : 'my_database'
    })
    connection.connect();
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because connect to sql just one time and don't need use middleware:

You should do like that:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file name connection.js

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "",
database: "wishyouife",
multipleStatements : true
});
mysqlConnection.connect((err) => {
if(!err){
    console.log("Connected");
}
else{
    console.log("Connection Failed");
}
});
module.exports = mysqlConnection;
```

Then on your app.js file you can import this module as:

```
const mysqlConnection = require('./connection');
```

Now wherever you want to perform a query, just go like

```
mysqlConnection.query("YOUR QUERY HERE");
```